# Curl Option for page without html

Tags: php, curl

I am creating a nagios that will automatically login to my website and display result in Nagios. Currenlty I am able to login using script but my PHP Curl script return full HTML code after login thourgh curl.

here is my script.

```
<?php
$id = "username";
$pw = "password";
$postfields = "userName=farooq&password=hussaind";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // Get the header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // Allow redirection
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://abc.com/signin.htm");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2) ");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$postfields");
curl_exec($ch);
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
# echo $statusCode;
if ($statusCode >= 200) {
echo 'OK - Status Code = '. $statusCode . '. Successfully Login' ;
exit (0);
}
else if ($statusCode >= 400){
echo 'CRITICAL - Status Code = '. $statusCode . '. Unable to loging. Please check ';
exit(2);
}
else {
echo 'UNKOWN - Status Code = '. $statusCode . '. Unable to loging. Please check ';
exit(1);
}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

I just want simple message to print without any HTML crap. Like

OK - Status Code = 200 Successfully Login

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks
Farooq Hussain

Comment: do not use closing tag "?>" if you do not really need it. It will save you from problems in future (usually infamous "headers already sent")

Answer (score 1):

Set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php